# Numeric Form Input Limit to Max value and use it to calculate 2nd field with it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

i'm new to Ionic and I've started with Ionic 4.
What i need to do is the following, i have a form that displays 3 fields to the user:

- 1st one (acumulados) is readonly where users can see the points they've won so far.
- 2nd (puntoscanje) is the amount of points the user wants to exchange for money they enter the numeric value.
- 3rd (descuento) is readonly field where in the background with the amount of points the user entered is going to calculate the money they're going to exchange for points.

My problem is and i have this done in html with a javascript function using DOM, but I've read that its not recommended to do it that way so i'm trying to get it working with ionic and angular.

This is the example javascript code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("puntoscanje").value > <?php echo $puntos ?> ) {
    document.getElementById("puntoscanje").value = <?php echo $puntos ?>;   
  }
  var puntoscanje = document.getElementById("puntoscanje").value;
  var PuntosDescto = <?php echo $PuntosDescto ?> ;
  document.getElementById("descuento").value = (puntoscanje / PuntosDescto).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

In the form i have the input called "puntoscanje", the user can modify this field entering a number, 
i need to check the number the user set after changes have been done `((ionChange))` in the field and then calculate a 2nd field, i'm trying to do it with a function to set the value BUT, sometimes it work sometimes it doesn't.
For example:

If the max value is 170, and the user writes down 200 it verifies each number like this:

```
2>170 = doesn't change
20>170 = doesn't change
200>170 = changes and it sets the value to 170 (the max value).
```

BUT if i type on the input 170 first, and then another number like 1702 and so on it doesn't change.

**Page ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { GetService } from '../../get.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-canjepuntos',
      templateUrl: './canjepuntos.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./canjepuntos.page.scss'],
    })
    export class CanjepuntosPage implements OnInit {
      points: any;
      puntoscanje: any;
      descuento: any;
      pcanje: any;

      constructor(private storage: Storage,) { 
        this.storage.get('Puntos').then((val) => {
          this.points = parseInt(val);
          //console.log('Your Name is', val);
        });
       }
      myFunction() {
        console.log(this.puntoscanje);
        if( this.puntoscanje > this.points){
          this.puntoscanje = this.points;
        }
          var PuntosDescto = 10 ;
          var calculo = ( this.puntoscanje / PuntosDescto).toFixed(2);
          this.descuento = calculo;        
      }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

template:

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="dark">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Canje de Puntos</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
      <form  #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(form)">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row justify-content-center>
            <ion-col align-self-center>
              <div padding class="form-inputs">
                <ion-item  >
                    <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">Puntos Acumulados</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" name="acumulados" [(ngModel)]="acumulados" value="{{points}}" readonly style="text-align: center;"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">Puntos a Canjear</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="puntoscanje" name="puntoscanje" autofocus="true" [(ngModel)]="puntoscanje" style="text-align: center;" min="0" max="{{points}}" (ionChange)="myFunction()" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">descuento</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="descuento" name="descuento" [(ngModel)]="descuento" style="text-align: center;" max="{{points}}" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>


              </div>
              <div style="padding-top:100px">
              <ion-button style="width:150px; height: 50px; margin: auto; " expand="block" (click)="Login()" >Canjear</ion-button>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
```

Thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is a bit a manual work. Just prevent the default event, and handle the numbers.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { GetService } from '../../get.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canjepuntos',
  templateUrl: './canjepuntos.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canjepuntos.page.scss'],
})
export class CanjepuntosPage implements OnInit {

points: any;
puntoscanje: any = 0; //You need to initialize a value for puntoscanje
descuento: any;
pcanje: any;


  constructor(private storage: Storage,) { 
    this.storage.get('Puntos').then((val) => {
      this.points = parseInt(val);
      //console.log('Your Name is', val);
    });
   }



   myFunction(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.puntoscanje = Number(`${this.puntoscanje}${event.key}`)
     if (isNaN(this.puntoscanje)) {
       this.puntoscanje = 0;
     }
     if( this.puntoscanje >= this.points){
       this.puntoscanje = this.points;
     }
     var PuntosDescto = 10 ;
     var calculo = ( this.puntoscanje / PuntosDescto).toFixed(2);
     this.descuento = calculo;
   }

 }
```

**Template**

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Canje de Puntos</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form  #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(form)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row justify-content-center>
        <ion-col align-self-center>
          <div padding class="form-inputs">
            <ion-item  >
                <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">Puntos Acumulados</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" name="acumulados" [(ngModel)]="acumulados" value="{{points}}" readonly style="text-align: center;"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">Puntos a Canjear</ion-label>
              <<ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="puntoscanje" name="puntoscanje" autofocus="true" [(ngModel)]="puntoscanje" style="text-align: center;" min="0" max="{{points}}" (keypress)="myFunction($event)" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-label position="stacked" style="text-align: center;">descuento</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="descuento" name="descuento" [(ngModel)]="descuento" style="text-align: center;" max="{{points}}" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>


          </div>
          <div style="padding-top:100px">
          <ion-button style="width:150px; height: 50px; margin: auto; " expand="block" (click)="Login()" >Canjear</ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I tried the code above, but get this message in console:
The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: Still having the issue, the message in console appears when i clear the whole input and it gets to be empty

Comment: I edited the question, I'm not getting that error but I think that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, i added an extra thing an (ionChange) on the input field to a second to a different process just to make sure its not NaN or undefined.
if (this.puntoscanje == undefined || this.puntoscanje == NaN ){
        this.puntoscanje = 0;
    }